# how to debug line by code - am using mpdf library php

Tags: dompdf, php-7.1

dompdf loadhtml will work but after dompdf render system not responding , here html is having image urls(complete path) also and has style css separate file......

$dompdf->loadHtml($htmlWithStyles);
$dompdf->render();